# Enable Run button for Service add-on in Kodi

Tags: add-on, kodi

I am contributing to the Kodi [PartyMode AutoStart](https://github.com/elbowz/partymode-autostart-xbmc-service/) add-on.

I would like to add the option to manually trigger the plugin using Kodi's existing "Run" button for add-ons (which is disabled at the moment), so that users can test their settings without having to reboot the device.

I assume that the button is disabled because the add-on is a Service add-on, which are designed to run (per [Kodi documentation](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on_structure#Directory_Name)) at startup or upon login.

My question: is there something I can set in the `.py` or settings file to enable this Run button, and trigger the plugin, or would I need to change the entire add-on type?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you can follow answer suggested by @Razze but for only testing purpose you can create your own executable addon to run your script with `RunScript()`

Comment: @Gahan that is not really an option, because I want the Run button to work so that _end users_ can easily test their settings.

Comment: The GUI decides whether to enable the Run button (which is called Select in the source code) based on the output of several functions, one of which is [CanRun()](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/xbmc/addons/GUIDialogAddonInfo.cpp#L378). It will return true if `m_localAddon` is non-null and of type `ADDON_SCRIPT`, so I don't see why the button would be disabled in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple extension points in your `addon.xml` so your service can also have a script extension point and act on that. So you would have both these.

```
<extension point="xbmc.python.script" library="defaultscript.py">
    <provides>executable</provides>
</extension>
```

See:
https://github.com/trakt/script.trakt/blob/master/addon.xml#L10-L13

Comment: This script already has that extension point, and still no Run button is enabled. See here: https://github.com/elbowz/partymode-autostart-xbmc-service/blob/master/addon.xml#L11-L13

Comment: It seems that that extension point is activated by the "Configure" button, not the "Run" button as shown in the screen shot above.